# which is the best way to customize nav-menu-template.php?

Tags: theme-development, customization, menus

I have modified the function `start_el` in `nav-menu-template.php` substituting `$item->ID` with `$item->title` so that the html `li` elements in menu have a more readable class names. In detail, I have changed the line

```
$id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
```

to

```
$id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->title, $item, $args );
```

This makes the editing of the `style.css` file for a theme easier. 
I wonder if it is possible to "transfer" the change from `nav-menu-template.php` to the theme (maybe `functions.php`?), so that I will not be forced to modify the file every time I upgrade WP version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the following into your `functions.php`:

```
add_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'wpse64308_nav_menu_item_id',10,3);
function wpse64308_nav_menu_item_id( $id, $item, $args){
    return 'menu-item-'.$item->title;
}
```

Comment: well that's much easier!